# How to select photos that are in selected albums

Tags: mysql

I couldn't figure out how to word this question, so I'm going to use a typical example.  Imagine I have a common design for photo albums with 3 tables - photos, albums, photo_albums (a lookup table). Albums names are A, B and C.

How would I find all photos that are in both A and C?

Comment: if I understand correctly table name is `photos,albums,photo_albums`... and in the table of album have contain 3 image like `A,B,C` and you wants to find `A and C`.

Answer (score 1):

You first do a `JOIN` between `albums` and `photo_albums` and do a `GROUP BY` to find which photos are there in both albums A and C. Then JOIN this result with `photos` to get the final result.

Something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM photos p
JOIN (
  SELECT pa.photoid
  FROM albums a
  JOIN photos_albums pa
  ON a.albumid = pa.albumid
  WHERE a.albumname IN ('A','C')
  GROUP BY pa.photoid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(pa.albumid)) = 2
) t
ON p.photoid = t.photoid
```

**Working Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/187f36/20

Comment: This works. However, if you want photos in albums A, B and C, you would have to change the COUNT(DISTINCT(pa.albumid)) = 3.  Can you think of a query where all you need to do is supply the names of the albums you want?

Comment: @one09jason Change `2` with this: `LENGTH(CONCAT_WS(',','A','C')) - LENGTH(CONCAT('A','C')) + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

If your table design look like this and you want to filter on the album name. Then you can do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    photos
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        photo_albums
        JOIN albums
            ON photo_albums.albumId=albums.albumId
    WHERE
        photos.photoId=photo_albums.photoId
        AND albums.albumName IN ('A','B')
)
```

I think the better solution would be to do it via the Id if you have one. Like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    photos
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        photo_albums
    WHERE
        photos.photoId=photo_albums.photoId
        AND photo_albums.albumId IN (1,3)
)
```

Comment: This seems to work to get photos that are in albums A OR C, not A and C.